# Google Apps Script server call to populate select list never runs

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, html-select

I'm creating a sidebar in a Google sheet.  I have no problem getting it to appear with select lists.  I'm trying to populate the select lists based on a range in one of the sheets.  I've tried numerous suggestions from stackoverflow and I've read Google's documentation for the HTML Service many times.  I still seem to be missing something.  From my testing, it appears that the google.script.run call to the server is never executed.  Here is my code.gs file:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Schedule')
      .addItem('New schedule', 'newSchedule')
      .addItem('Edit start date', 'newDate')
      .addSeparator()
      .addItem('Insert names', 'openInsert')  
      .addToUi();
}


function openInsert() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Insert')
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
    .setTitle('Insert Names')
    .setWidth(300);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .showSidebar(html);
}


function getNames() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Publishers");
  var names = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
  return names;
}
```

Here is my Insert.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css">

  <script>

  function returnedNames(names) {
    var selectList = new Array("publisher1","publisher2","publisher3");

    for (sel in selectList) {
      var dropDown = document.getElementById(sel);

      for (i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
        var opt = document.createElement("option");
        opt.text = names[i][0];
        opt.values = names[i][0];
        dropDown.options.add(opt);
      }
    }
  }

  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(returnedNames).getNames();

  </script>

  </head>

  <body>

  <div class="block form-group">
    <label for="publisher1">First publisher</label>
    <select id="publisher1"> </select>
    <label for="publisher2">Second publisher</label>
    <select id="publisher2"> </select>
    <label for="publisher3">Third publisher (optional)</label>
    <select id="publisher3"> </select>
  </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your server function is being called before your document is actually ready to be worked on. I'd imagine that if you checked the browser console window with developer tools, you'd see an error pop up.

Since you essentially want these populated onload, add a load event to the body tag. Have that event call your server function. If this doesn't work use a combination of Logger.log on the server side and console.log on the client side through out your sequence of code and see what you get and what path your code follows.

Comment: That's what I thought, that the function is called before the doc is ready. I already tried adding a load event to the body tag but it didn't work. I'll try again in case I did it wrong before. I'll try your suggestion of logging to see the path.  Are there any other methods to ensure that the function is fired at the right time?  Most code samples use a button but a load event would be more appropriate.

Comment: I believe JQuery has a document ready event, pretty much the same thing as onload. You could also try using the failure handlers for Google.script.run to also follow the path of the code in case there is an error.

Comment: You're right.  The browser console has this error: userCodeAppPanel:13 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of null

Comment: Ah there it is, right under the first for loop you should have this: ’var dropDown = document.getElementById(selectList[sel]);’

Comment: You got it!  It was a combination of the body onload event and the error in that line.  I'm not an expert in JavaScript so can you explain why I had to still reference the array?  I thought sel in the for loop would contain the item.

Comment: If you've dealt with other programming languages, then you'll notice that this type of for loop is similar to the typical foreach loop. However, this type of for loop actual references the index of each item, rather than the item itself.